# Learning Drupal 7 and trying to understand themes and templates

Tags: drupal-7, themes

I'm new to learning Drupal and I'm hoping someone can explain something to me.  I'm trying to figure out how to change certain pages to have different template designs, for example one page can have a two column layout and one page can have a three column layout or one page can be a gallery.

Similar to this template from template monster.
http://www.templatemonster.com/drupal-themes/39996.html

So far all I have seen in terms of tutorials is just installing and setting up a theme and arranging the blocks around the site but nothing about changing templates.

I'm use to the way Wordpress does everything where with just one click in the dashboard you can change the template design of the page. If someone can explain how they differ and how they are similar that would be great!

Also if their is a good book on Drupal 7 please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations on beginning your trek into learning Drupal. It is, in my opinion, the best of the CMS's available today.

Drupal templates are controlled when logged in as a user with site administration in the 'Appearance' section. There, you can add a new theme or switch between those themes already installed on your site.

As for site themes displaying different page layouts depending on the which page you browse, as a general rule Drupal treats your home page differently than internal pages. Using modules such as the [Pages](http://drupal.org/project/pages) module, you can control the appearance, layout and functionality of specific pages of your site.

There are a number of excellent books on Drupal 7 that cover basic as well as intermediate topics. My favorite is [Drupal 7 Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005LVN67W) by David Ipswich.

Best of luck!